# Consolidate excel data in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I get an error on consolidate data using vb.net. Please help.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Public Class Form1
    Dim xlsWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim xlsApp As New Excel.Application
    xlsApp.Visible = True
    Dim xlsWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\hwai\Desktop\Consolidate.xlsx")
    lsWorkSheet.Range("H1").Select().Consolidate("'C:\Users\hwai\Desktop\[Consolidate.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1:B8", _Function:=-4112, TopRow:=False, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False)
End Sub
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: `xlsWorkSheet` is not defined.

Comment: that xlsWorkSheet already define, the suggest edit remove my word

Comment: What error? Please be a bit more specific regarding what's going on.

Comment: Error:"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Move `Dim xlsWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet` inside the sub.

Comment: @JLILIAmen [Dim xlsWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet] inside sub I get [Variable 'xlsWorkSheet' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime]

Comment: Is there any mention of Xlsworksheet in your class other than the one in your code sample?

Comment: @JLILIAmen there are no mention Xlsworksheet in my class other than one

Comment: The error is self explanatory. You might want to add `XlsWorksheet = Xls.workbook.Worksheets(1)` before the select line.

Comment: @JLILIAmen get another error [Public member 'Consolidate' on type 'Boolean' not found.]